# "This server version is not supported.Only Up To Microsoft SQL server 2005 are supported" in Visual Studio 2008 Cannot Connect to SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

Getting this error "This server version is not supported.Only Up To Microsoft SQL server 2005 are supported" after I create a data connection in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and SQL server 2008 R2. Any ideas would be great.

No other version of SQL server Installed.

The error occurs after I select server, then database. 
Just as I click OK I get that message.

Comment: Do you have other versions installed as well? Does it give the error on connection, or when you try a particular select? Does it also say " Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 are supported"?

Comment: @SteveCav No other version of SQL server Installed.

The error occurs after I select server, then database. Just as I click OK I get that message.

.Only Up To Microsoft SQL server 2005 are supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing SQL Server R2 I reinstalled VS 2008 SP1, this fixed my issue:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en